# Git branch name in .bashrc doesn't get updated

Tags: bash

All the below code shows current branch if terminal is opened directly in a folder where git is initialized. But if we change dir from a non git dir to a git initialized dir then its wont show up.

```sh
gitBranch="$(echo $(__git_ps1))"
PS1="[\@] (\u) \W ${gitBranch}
$ "
```

```sh
git_status() {
    echo $(__git_ps1)
}
PS1="[\@] (\u) \W $(git_status)
$ "
```

Answer (score 0):

`__git_ps1` gets run only once when you define gitBranch. Try :

```
__git_ps1(){ git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD 2>/dev/null || echo "(Not-git-repo)"; }

PS1='[\@] (\u) \W $(__git_ps1)
$ '
```

Answer (score 0):

The displayed branch does not change because it is hardcoded into the prompt. In the assignment `variable="..."` every `$(...)` inside the double quoted string is expanded once on assignment. In your prompt you want to expand `$(git_status)` at each prompt, so you have to quote `$()` in such a way that it is not expanded yet. Either use `"\$()"` or `'$()'`.

```
PS1='[\@] (\u) \W $(git_status)
$ '
```